Uploading session data from Express js server to Redis
I am trying to upload the session data to redis whenever a user logs in onto my react native app.  Im getting this error "Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisKey'.ts(2345)
(property) Document<unknown, any, any>._id?: unknown
This documents _id." On this line -> redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user) as any);
Here is the full code.
require("dotenv").config();
import { Response } from "express";
import { IUser } from "../models/user.model";
import { redis } from "./redis";
import { RedisKey } from "ioredis";
import { ObjectId } from "mongoose";

interface ITokenOptions {
  expires: Date;
  maxAge: number;
  httpOnly: boolean;
  sameSite: "lax" | "strict" | "none" | undefined;
  secure?: boolean;
}

export const sendToken = (user: IUser, statusCode: number, res: Response) => {
  const accessToken = user.SignAccessToken();
  const refreshToken = user.SignRefreshToken();

  //upload session to redis
  redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user) as any);


  //parse environment variables to integrate with fallback values
  const accessTokenExpire = parseInt(
    process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE || "300",
    10
  );
  const refreshTokenExpire = parseInt(
    process.env.ACCESS_REFRESH_EXPIRE || "1200",
    10
  );

  //options for cookies
  const accessTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + accessTokenExpire * 1000),
    maxAge: accessTokenExpire * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "lax",
  };

  const refreshTokenOptions: ITokenOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + refreshTokenExpire * 1000),
    maxAge: refreshTokenExpire * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "lax",
  };

  //only sent secure to true in production
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    accessTokenOptions.secure = true;
  }

  res.cookie("access_token", accessToken, accessTokenOptions);
  res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, refreshTokenOptions);

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    accessToken,
  });
};


Im expecting the json data to be uploaded onto redis

Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisKey'.
redis.set(user._id, JSON.stringify(user) as any)

first lines are error and second line is code, im trying upload session data to redis

use
const userId = String(user._id); // Safely convert _id to a string
const userData = JSON.stringify(user); // Serialize the user object
redis.set(userId, userData); // Store the data in Redis

Thanks for contributing! Could you provide examples showing how to switch from require to import and configure AWS Lambda for ES modules (e.g., .mjs extension or package.json update)? Adding more context and links to documentation would make your answer clearer and more valuable for future readers.
